# Api Platform 2.5: execute collectionOperations only when the current entity is nested

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I started using API Platform after having a good documentation and watching a professionnel tutoriel, and now I encountered a problem.

I have two entities User & Role, the Role is nested in User.
I want to disable direct operations on Role, I want only when I post a User with Role, the post operation works but when I post directly on Role /api/roles, the post operation have to be disabled.

## User:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={
 *        "groups"={"get"}
 *      },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')",
 *               "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"get"}
 *              }
 *          },
 *          "put"= {
 *              "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') or is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') and object.getAuthor() == user",
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"put"}
 *              }
 *          }
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"
 *          },
 *          "post"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')",
 *              "denormalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"user:post"}
 *              }
 *          }
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username","email"})
 */
class  User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"get","get_comment_with_author","get_post_with_comments"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Groups({"get","user:post","get_comment_with_author","get_post_with_comments"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Groups({"put","user:post","get_comment_with_author","get-to-admin"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", fetch="EAGER")
     * @Groups({"put","user:post"})
     */
    private $rolesCollection;
```

## Role:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"user:post"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations) (but the `get` operation) like this:

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get"},
 *     itemOperations={"get"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"user:post"})
     */
    private $id;
...
}
```

Now you can only read the Roles, but not create or edit them.